# STM32F4 Discovery

Tags: distance, iar, measure, discovery, stm32f4

I have STM32F4 Discovery. I use IAR embedded Workbench. I am new to this kit. I want to measure distance. my code does not give an error. the distance is always zero. What could be the error? please help me . thanks everyone

```
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"
#include "delay.h"

uint32_t Read_Distance(void);
void Init();

uint32_t distance ;

int main()
{  
    Init();   // initialisation de pin
    SysTick_Init(); // pour pouvoire utiliser la fonction delay :)

    while (1)
    {
        distance=Read_Distance();
        delay_nms(100);
    }
}


void Init()
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioStructure;

    gpioStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpioStructure);

    gpioStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpioStructure);
}

//Les Pins pour le Test sont PD10 (Trig) et PD11(echo) 

uint32_t Read_Distance(void)
{
    __IO uint8_t flag=0;
    __IO uint32_t disTime=0;
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_10);
    delay_nus(10);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_10);

    while(flag == 0)
    {
        while(GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_11) == SET)
        {
            disTime++;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    return disTime;
}
```

Comment: I edited the indentation of your code so it is consistent. I highly recommend you to do the same for all your code, especially all code you post. That makes it infinitely easier to read. Further, try to post comments in english. A simple english comment is more helpful than an elaborate french comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using one of those ultrasonic distance measurement modules

Try this:

```
while(flag == 0)
{
   disTime++;
   if(GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_11) == SET)
   {
     flag = 1;
   }
}
```

You should use one of the hardware timers to get a more accurate time measurement.

Now I've had time to think more about it I remember now that you get a pulse sent back with a width proportional to the distance. I think this is the correct answer:

```
// Wait for pulse to start
while (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_11) == RESET)
{
    NOP;
}

// Measure pulse width
while(flag == 0)
{
   disTime++;
   // Has pulse ended
   if(GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_11) == RESET)
   {
     flag = 1;
   }
}
```

You may also want to tackle the case where the pulse is never received because this could will block forever.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, D10 is wired to D11 and you want to check how long your signal remains high. If this is the case, you should increment a counter in timer interrupt handler when your pin is high and reset that counter variable once you've read it.